# Access [[scope]] of the function from api response

Tags: javascript, scope

```
drop: (item, monitor) => addTaskToSprint(item.id, monitor, drop)
    length: 2
    name: "drop"
    arguments: (...)
    caller: (...)
    [[FunctionLocation]]: SprintCard.jsx:45
    [[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
        0: Closure (SprintCard)
           ItemType: "Task Card"
           addTaskToSprint: (id, monitor, dropTargetProps, task) => {…}
           drop: ƒ ()
```

My api response looks like this,

I need to access [[Scopes]] so I can get the ItemType variable

drop is a function so accessing the scope like so (spec.drop.scopes) won't work

when I console.log(spec.drop) it shows the function declaration only

So is there any way to have access scopes?

Comment: Just FYI: The reason I added the [tag:javascript] tag because this was clearly JavaScript-related, and removed the [tag:json] because what's shown clearly isn't JSON or JSON-derived, as it has functions in it. (JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange, which doesn't have a way to represent functions. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) Basically, if you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.)

Answer (score 2):

[[Scopes]] isn't a part of the object, it's a category devtools uses to show what [environment record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-environment-records) objects a function closes over. The `drop` function has access to `ItemType`, but other code doesn't get access to `ItemType` via `drop` unless `drop` provides that access in some way. More generally, code with access to a function doesn't necessarily have access to the things that function has access to (in fact, it often doesn't).

Here's a simpler example:

```js
function counter() {
    let value = 0;
    const increment = () => ++value;
    return increment;
}

function example() {
    const increment = counter();
    console.log(increment()); // Shows "1"
    console.log(increment()); // Shows "2" -- that is, the `increment`
                              // function closes over `value` so it
                              // can use it to return an incrementing
                              // counter

    // There's no way for code here to directly access the `value` that
    // `increment` closes over.
}

example();
```

The `increment` function has access to `value`, but the `example` function does not, even though it has access to `increment`.

Comment: Did you mean to have the second log as `console.log(value);` to show that it's `undefined`?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi - No, the `console.log`s are there to show using `increment`. I see what you mean, though, it does kinda look like an editing error. :-) (Edit: I've updated the answer a bit to clarify.)